# VB - Print Word Document hidden / Visible = False

Tags: vb.net

I need to print a document and have the application hidden. I am using Microsoft Word 2010.

I have tried to hide the application with the code shown below in the Yellow Comments.

> objWord.Visible = False
>
> &
>
> objDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = False

but the window still appear at this line:

```
objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("T:\Helsingborg\A\Transport\2. Transportdrift\11. M-trp\Fraktsedlar\Växjö\Växjö Mall.doc")
```

And becomes hidden as soon as it gets to:

```
objDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = False
```

I really can't find any way to solve this, since I can't use `ActiveWindow.Visible = False` before the document is opened.

This is my current code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' Step 1
    Dim objWord
    objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    ' Hidden window!
    objWord.Visible = False
    ' Save the original printer, otherwise you will reset the system default!
    Dim previousPrinter
    previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter
    objWord.ActivePrinter = ""

    ' Step 2
    Dim objDoc
    objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("T:\Helsingborg\A\....\Växjö Mall.doc")
    objDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    ' Step 3 -- in this case, print out the document without any prompts
    objDoc.PrintOut
    ' Restore the original printer
    objWord.ActivePrinter = previousPrinter

    ' Step 4
    objDoc.Close

    ' Step 5
    objWord.Quit

    MsgBox("Everything is now printed") ' Change to custom MSGBOX

End Sub
```

EDIT: An alternative would be if I can print the word document without opening Word.

Comment: Have you tried setting Documents.Open()'s optional parameter "Visible:=False"?

Comment: to add to what @soohoonigan said...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Hey, doesn't work. It briefly shows the document on the screen before it disappears.
I rewrote it like this `objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(LinDocPath, Visible = False)` I also tried "Visible:=False" @soohoonigan

Answer (score 0):

```
set objDoc = GetObject(Filename)
set objWord = objDoc.Parent
```

in place of the Documents.Open statement

```
objDoc.Close False
```